# Python &amp; in url string

Tags: python, string, url, jupyter-lab

Today I updated my env to python 3.8.2 Suddenly all URL strings have `&amp;` rather than `&`.

I have tried to do the following:

```
import urllib.parse

params = {'pam1' : '1', 'pam2' : 2}
encoded = "https://someURL?" + urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
```

but the output is still the same

`'https://someURL?pam1=1&amp;pam2=2'`

Is this new expected behavior? I have never encountered this and it worked fine before.

I am using the Jupyter lab.

Comment: I have tried your code and my output is https://someURL?pam1=1&pam2=2 as expected. If you try it on a blank jupyter workbook, do you still get this result?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it in a couple of blank notebooks I still can't get the expected result.

Comment: I do not observe this when I test this in a Python 3.8 shell, test it online https://www.python.org/shell/

Comment: yes, it seems its a jupyter notebook issue. It works just fine in the shell for me too.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Jupyter trying to automatically convert links into clickable hyperlinks. It is fixed in more recent Jupyter version. Try to update your Jupyter installation